# как настроить sshuttle для работы с docker?

Tags: docker, vpn, localhost

Локально с помощью докера развернут сайт, появилась необходимость использовать sshuttle как vpn, в проекте есть запросы к стороннему сервису который смотрит с какого ip к нему обращаются.

Не понимаю как настроить окружение так, чтобы локальная копия проекта могла работать через sshuttle.

ОС на моей локальной машине Ubuntu 20.04, проблем с подключением к удаленному хосту чей ip хочу использовать нет.

Пробовал локально, не в контейнере, выполнять команду: `sshuttle -r MY_REMOTE_HOST 0.0.0.0/0 -vv`

В результате локальный сайт mysite.loc перестает вообще открываться. 100% делаю что-то не так, возможно стоит поправить конфиги для контейнеров или еще что-то?

В докере не силен, только начал осваивать, поэтому буду рад любым советам или примерам.

**Решение:**
`sshuttle -l 0.0.0.0:0 -r MY_REMOTE_HOST -x 127.0.0.1 -x 10.101.0.0/24  0/0 --dns`

Параметром -x исключаем перенаправление трафика для нужных ip адресов, в моем случае это localhost(127.0.0.1) и подсеть докер контейнеров 10.101.0.0/24.

Для определения адреса подсети докера можно воспользоваться командами:

- `docker network ls`, получим список сетей network_id
- `docker network inspect network_id`, выводим подробную информацию о сети